# Add Custom Parameter to IdentityServer4 Auth Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Is there any way to add a custom parameter to identityserver auth request. I tried this way. but it will add parameters return URL, not as auth request query strings.

```
 Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
        {
            if (context.Properties.Items.ContainsKey("connection"))
                context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("connection", context.Properties.Items["connection"]);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
```

but I need to have those parameters on request URL not a parameter of return url..

Answer (score 0):

The request url looks like:

```
https://login.dev.domain.com/connect/authorize?client_id=657ce44e-10a2-4b66-9078-7f1acf92811f&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.dev.domain.com%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636888568253105245.ODY4MzNjNGMtZDQxYi00YTkzLTg5OTctNTJkZGRjM2IwNGRjMjEwMWEzZGQtYWY1Mi00ODQ0LWE0ZGYtZTAxOWU0YjQyODkz&ui_locales=en&state=CfDJ8F-9xHJQT19NjH-KMvnd4SnuYPsaINrq_yn6DAfN8Y6h5aHBoukF0TPqZHOYk0mroCw4tz-03ajp6cgaomZ8HnrE6Or6ZzzNdfUqzDpDNH4VwWCax8JwtsRreob9j-nsOnttzDkRVTCzVEjjHpR__OR498c-kVXf-RjudGPghE0K&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD1_4&x-client-ver=5.2.0.0
```

where, in my case `ui_locales=en` is my custom parameter. It's not a part of `redirect_uri`, just one more query parameter, separated by `&` signs. That works when you need to pass some data to your IdP. When you need just to keep some data during the request and get it back with authorization response, you can involve the State pre-defined parameter.

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect(Constants.MyIdpName, Constants.MyIdpName, options => {
***           
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents {
     OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx => {
          var rcf = ctx.HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
              if (rcf.Provider != null) {
                    string lng = rcf.RequestCulture.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
                    ctx.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("ui_locales", lng == "nn" || lng == "nb" ? "no" : lng);
              }
              return Task.CompletedTask;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: added some, but it looks exact like yours

Comment: Yes it just adding params to redirect Url not query string params

Comment: no, my example Url demonstrates that :)  Or, maybe you mean something hidden for me? What is the "query string" you wish to modify?